# Google Cloud Hadoop Nodes not yet sshable error

Tags: cygwin, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, google-hadoop

**I ran the following commands referring to https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/setting-up-a-hadoop-cluster on cygwin.**

```
gsutil.cmd mb -p [projectname] gs://[bucketname]      
./bdutil -p [projectname] -n 2 -b [bucketname] -e hadoop2_env.sh      
generate_config configuration.sh   
./bdutil -e configuration.sh deploy
```

**After deployment, I am getting the following errors:**
.
.
.

```
Node 'hadoop-w-0' did not become    ssh-able after 10 attempts  
Node    'hadoop-w-1' did not become ssh-able after 10 attempts  
Node 'hadoop-m' did not become ssh-able after 10    attempts
```

Command failed: wait    ${SUBPROC} on line 308.

Exit code of    failed command: 1

Detailed debug info    available in file:  /tmp/bdutil-20150120-103601-mDh/debuginfo.txt*

**The logs in debuginfo.txt are like these:**

```
******************* Exit codes and VM logs *******************
Tue, Jan 20, 2015 10:18:09 AM: Exited 1 : gcloud.cmd --project=[projectname] --quiet --verbosity=info compute ssh hadoop-w-0 --command=exit 0 --ssh-flag=-oServerAliveInterval=60 --ssh-flag=-oServerAliveCountMax=3 --ssh-flag=-oConnectTimeout=30 --zone=us-central1-a    
Tue, Jan 20, 2015 10:18:09 AM: Exited 1 : gcloud.cmd --project=[projectname] --quiet --verbosity=info compute ssh hadoop-w-1 --command=exit 0 --ssh-flag=-oServerAliveInterval=60 --ssh-flag=-oServerAliveCountMax=3 --ssh-flag=-oConnectTimeout=30 --zone=us-central1-a   
Tue, Jan 20, 2015 10:18:09 AM: Exited 1 : gcloud.cmd --project=[projectname] --quiet --verbosity=info compute ssh hadoop-w-2 --command=exit 0 --ssh-flag=-oServerAliveInterval=60 --ssh-flag=-oServerAliveCountMax=3 --ssh-flag=-oConnectTimeout=30 --zone=us-central1-a
```

Could you please help me in resolving this issue?. Thank you a lot.

Comment: Prior to running bdutil, were you able to SSH into a GCE VM doing a manual VM creation? It can be easy to miss, but this step is necessary before running bdutil: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances#sshing (mentioned on "Configure gcutil ssh" on page https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/). It must be configured without a passphrase.

Comment: Thank you @Dennis Huo.   No. This hasn't been done. But I was able to ssh using google cloud SDK so I didn't set this up. I will try and tell you.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to look at the console output for your Hadoop instances, from within the Developers console > Compute Engine > VM Instances > INSTANCE_NAME > scroll down to View Console Output .

Additionally you can run :

> $ gcloud compute instances get-serial-port-output INSTANCE_NAME

- this should give you a better picture of what is going on behind the scenes when the instances are booted (check if SSH daemon has started and on which port..etc.).